# Less than and Greater than symbols together

Tags: perl

I came across this piece of code:

```
#!perl
use strict;
my %hash;
while(my $line = <>) {
  chomp($line);
  $hash{$line}++;
}
map {print $_ ."\n"} keys %hash;
```

I want to understand the meaning of the statement `while(my $line = <>)` and `map {print $_ ."\n"} keys %hash;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<>` isn't a regular expression, it's how you read from handles.

Here's the perl documentation on [I/O operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators).

Specifically:

> The null filehandle <> is special: it can be used to emulate the behavior of sed and awk, and any other Unix filter program that takes a list of filenames, doing the same to each line of input from all of them. Input from <> comes either from standard input, or from each file listed on the command line. Here's how it works: the first time <> is evaluated, the @ARGV array is checked, and if it is empty, $ARGV[0] is set to "-", which when opened gives you standard input. The @ARGV array is then processed as a list of filenames.

So unless you have file names specified via `@ARGV`, doing `<>` will read from standard input.

Comment: thanks! I thought it is 'not equal to'!

Comment: Can you also explain what is the meaning of the statements `while(my $line = <>)` and `map {print $_ ."\n"} keys %hash;`

Comment: The while statement does two things: first it assigns the read line to `$line`, then if `$line` is truthy it executes the block.  Usually this is used to execute a block of code for each line of input.  The `map` function is [explained here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html).  Seriously though, check the perldocs.  They're quite helpful.

Comment: @chandra: Some languages use `<>` as a "not equal" operator. Perl isn't one of them. Perl, like C, uses `!=` for inequality (or, unlike C, `ne` for string operands).

Comment: It is best not to enter into question/answer dialogues in the comments as it is impossible for others to search for such answers.

Answer (score 1):

`<>` isn't a regular expression, it's a `readline` from the null file handle.

If you write

```
while ( <STDIN> ) { ... }
```

then you are reading from the `STDIN` file handle.

But if you leave the `<>` empty then Perl will read from the `ARGV` file handle, which gives lines from all the files specified on the command line in sequence (the contents of `@ARGV`) or from `STDIN` (usually the keyboard) if `@ARGV` is empty.

Comment: thanks! Can you also explain what is the meaning of the statements while(my $line = <>) and map {print $_ ."\n"} keys %hash; ?

Comment: @chandra: Stack Overflow isn't a forum, and you should use comments only to clarify a question or solution, not to ask new questions. If you want to ask something else then post a new question, although I am sure that, with a little effort, you could work out the answer to that yourself. By the way, `map {print $_ ."\n"} keys %hash` is a misuse of `map` and should be `print "$_\n" for keys %hash`